# Interaction with locked ViewHolder in RecyclerView using ItemTouchHelper

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm using a custom `ItemTouchListener` to make my items in a `RecyclerView` swipeable. The `ViewHolders` have a `RelativeLayout` so when I'm swiping them left a pair of `Buttons` appear. But now my problem is that my `Buttons` are not clickable at the first touch after the swipe. I need to click the `ViewHolder` 3 times so i can interact with it again (clicking buttons, edit textviews).

In my custom `ItemTouchHelper` `onChildDraw` method I'm doing something like this to keep the `ViewHolder` at a specific position and make the buttons under the swipeable view visible:

```
if(dX > itemView.getWidth() / 4){
    dX = itemView.getWidth() / 4;
}
((CustomViewHolder) viewHolder).getSwipeAbleLayout().setTranslationX(dX);
```

It seems like the `ViewHolder` is still in swipe mode during the first two clicks.

Or does someone have a better solution to lock a `ViewHolder` at a specific position while swiping so that buttons appear which can be clicked to either remove the `ViewHolder` or swipe the `ViewHolder` back to normal position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by using following library: [AndroidSwipeLayout](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout)

It is pretty simple to use. Can recommend it to everyone who needs to work with "locked RecyclerView items".

Answer (score 1):

Consider using this github project - [itemtouchhelper-extension](https://github.com/loopeer/itemtouchhelper-extension). I got my all problem solved using that in my recent project. Its is having pretty good implmenation example as well. Try out.